# Hyperopt: Define parameter which is dependent on other parameter

Tags: parameters, hyperopt

I am using `python` package `hyperopt` and I have a parameter `a` which requires to be larger than parameter `b`.

For example, I hope my parameter space is like

```
from hyperopt import hp

space = {"b": hp.uniform(0, 0.5), "a": hp.uniform(b, 0.5)}
```

Which, requires `a` to be at least larger than `b`, how can I do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well one option is to run many evaluations and then choose the minimum from the cases which satisfy your constraint.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A simple option is to use the ability of `hyperopt` to nest parameters. You can thus define a hyper-parameter space like you want:

```
space = hp.uniform("a", hp.uniform("b", 0, 0.5), 0.5)
```

Only `"a"`'s value is passed to the function that you optimize (because this is the hyper-parameter space), but `hyperopt.fmin()` will return both parameters.

A similar option, but where the function to be optimized receives both parameters is:

```
b_var = hp.uniform("b", 0, 0.5)
space = {"b": b_var, "a": hp.uniform("a", b_var, 0.5)}
```

Finally, it might be simpler to change a bit the inputs to the optimized function: parameter `a` can be replaced by `a_fraction` running between 0 and 1 and interpolating between `b` and 0.5 (i.e. `a_fraction = 0` yields `a = b` and `a_fraction = 1` gives `a = 0.5` inside the modified function to be optimized). The parameter space thus has the usual form:

```
space = {"b": hp.uniform("b", 0, 0.5), "a_fraction": hp.uniform("a_fraction", 0, 1)}
```

There is an interesting discussion at https://github.com/hyperopt/hyperopt/issues/175#issuecomment-29401501.

Comment: That's very comprehensive. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have hyperopt 0.2.3 and when I try your first two solutions that involve putting one hp variable as an argument to another I get `TypeError: len of pyll.Apply either undefined or unknown`. Is this expected? Do these solutions no longer work?

Comment: Unfortunately, many things seem to have changed: hyperopt 0.2.3 doesn't even accept the very simple `hp.uniform(0, 0.5)` from the original question!

Comment: @EricOLebigot any idea how to do this on the current version of hyperopt?

Comment: Unfortunately no. However, you might want to look at the more recent and potentially more convenient optuna package.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my find could help someone. I was using HyperOpt to optimise parameters of a piecewise affine function.
Therefore I need nested parameters to properly set x parameters parts:

[image: piecewise function]
As nested parameters don't work (anymore) for HyperOpt, nor for Optuna... I recommend the [pwlf library](https://github.com/cjekel/piecewise_linear_fit_py) for all those who have the same problem.

This lib proposes 2 ways to extract the parameters of a piecewise linear function :

- By providing the number of parts
- By providing the breakpoint locations

If like me you are interested in finding the breakpoint locations you can provide the number of parts:

```
import pwlf
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    "x": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    "y": [0, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 7, 3, 1],
})

model = pwlf.PiecewiseLinFit(data.x, data.y)
nb_parts = 3
model.fit(nb_parts)

print(f"x part intersections: {model.fit_breaks}")
# x part intersections: [0. 1.99 6.00 9.]
print(f"linear coefficient of each part: {model.slopes}")
# linear coefficient of each part: [ 4.00,  1.00, -3.00]
print(f"linear bias of each part: {model.intercepts}")
# linear bias of each part: [-7.11e-06,  5.99e+00,  3.00e+01]
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I consider this an answer (not judging quality). So I removed your own statement that you consider it a comment. Please understand that if it really IS a comment you should not post it. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead

Comment: Please add a demonstration of how the lib you recommend can be used to solve the problem discussed at the top of this page. Only mentioning a tool/lib is not really considered an answer. You spend much more effort and I am generous in judging the "only" here. But please add some more info.